# WebHook call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, State: URL_TIMEOUT, Reason: TIMEOUT_WEB calling from node

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I am not sure what mistake I am doing. I have create a ChatBot in google dialog flow and did setup of WebHook in my local. Once I am hitting from dialogbox then reuqest is landing to code and processed successfully but in Dialogflow response I am getting failure due to some TimOut exception, there a way to fix this . I am facing WebHook  call failed. Error: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED, State: URL_TIMEOUT, Reason: TIMEOUT_WEB calling from node.
Below is the index.json snippet :
[image]

Below is the console log
[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the function you need to resolve the promise.

```
return Promise.resolve();
```

Additionally, you're probably already handling errors but in a `Firebase Function`, if you need to throw an error, you can do that simply this way:

```
throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
  'internal',
  'Woops, that should not happen.',
);
```